# C# With Asp.net MySQL with OBDC Making Login and Registration Not Working Problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, authentication, registration

I would be very grateful if someone could help me with a problem: registration page in C# for MySql using OBDC

I can't use any of the built in asp.net features.

I'm doing it for a class. And while I know there are other possibly better ways to make the connection string, this is how the instructor does it.
I have a class called User created, and am trying to make the registration page. Haven't started on the login page but need to do a login with session id and an entry on both login and registration pages that shoes if user is logged in or not.

So for starters, my registration page keeps getting an error on the `"NewRegis.create()" line 23.`

It also says:

```
c:\Users\Lau\Documents\SQL Class\Project_homework3\App_Code\User.cs(23,34): error CS1002: ; expected
        Line 21:                 NewRegis.email = email.Text;
        Line 22:                 NewRegis.password = password.Text;
        Line 23:                 NewRegis.create()
        Line 24:             }
        Line 25:
```

So here is the code for the registration aspx file and for the code behind file.....

Here is the code for the registration.aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="registration.aspx.cs" Inherits="registration.NewRegis" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
   <title></title>
   </head>
        <body>
            <div>
            <div>
            <h1>Registration Page</h1> 
            <p>To register, please enter the following information and then submit.</p>
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <div>
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:Label ID="EmailLab" runat="server" Text="Email Address (will be login)" 
                Value=""></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server" Width="205px"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="FirstName" runat="server" Text="First Name"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="first_name" runat="server" Width="205px"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="LastNameLab" runat="server" Text="Last Name"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="last_name" runat="server" Width="205px"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="passLab" runat="server" 
                Text="Password (Six Characters.)"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server" Width="205px"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />


<asp:Button ID="ButtonSubmit" OnClick="submit" PostBackUrl="~/registration.aspx" Text="Submit" runat="server" />

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqFieldValFirst" ControlToValidate="first_name" Text="First name is required!" runat="server" />  

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqFieldValLast" ControlToValidate="last_name" Text="Last name is required!" runat="server" /> 

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqFieldValEmail" ControlToValidate="email" Text="Email is required!" runat="server" /> 

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqFieldValPass" ControlToValidate="password" Text="Password is required!" runat="server" /> 

<br />
<br />
<br />

        </form>
     </div>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

---

Here is the code for the codebehind file where the NewRegis.create is getting an error:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace registration
{
    public partial class NewRegis : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (IsPostBack)
            {

                User NewRegis = new User()
                NewRegis.first_name = first_name.Text;
                NewRegis.last_name = last_name.Text;
                NewRegis.email = email.Text;
                NewRegis.password = password.Text;

                NewRegis.create();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### I didn't include the user class file but if that would help, I can reload it. I minimized this post at the request below.

I'd be grateful for any help on what I've got. I have no idea why I keep getting the error on the NewRegis.create();
but when I hover over the "User" in User in User NewRegis = new User() the tip tells me `'System.Web.UI.Page.User' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'`

Comment: Please split your problem into smallest parts. and remember `less code == fastest helps`

Answer (score 0):

Took some time to wade through all of it ;-)

```
error CS1002: ; expected
```

means as it says that you forgot a terminating semicolon at the end of a line. Solving that should be trivial to you, right?

```
System.Web.UI.Page.User is a 'property' but is used like a 'type
```

The compiler interprets your user class the same as System.Web.UI.Page.User property. A name conflict.

You can solve it by renaming your User-class to something else like `MyUser`, not just alter the namespace(!)

Or specify the full qualified name of the class, in your case

```
PET.User NewRegis = new PET.User();
```

Comment: I don't think it is a semi colon but thank you.  I will try the renaming suggestion tho. Thanks much for the suggestions.

Comment: There was a semi colon. You were right. But fixing it didn't make the error go away, unfortunately. Changing the names didn't work either but thanks for trying.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I had created an extra class that I didn't need. However, I still have an error in the above mentioned area. I may start a separate post with the new code however. Not sure what the protocol is here.

Comment: I've resolved a lot of the problems but have this one now. The namespace appears to be correct so I don't know why it's not loading.

Comment: I have resolved many problems but have a parsing error and it won't load the namespace, unfortunately. Not sure if that should go here or some place else like a new thread...... Thanks for all the help.