# C# Login Mysql OBDC Class and Type Confusion/ Error

Tags: c#, mysql, class, authentication

I'm working on a registration login page in c# with MySql and OBDC. I have no experience in C# so I'm really struggling (this is for a class). I'm having some confusion about classes vs. types vs. objects.

Here is the error that's coming up, followed by the code (any help is greatly appreciated):

c:\Users\Lau\Documents\SQL Class\Project_homework3\registration.aspx.cs(23,25): error CS0118: 'System.Web.UI.Page.User' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'
c:\Users\Lau\Documents\SQL Class\Project_homework3\registration.aspx.cs(23,44): error CS0118: 'System.Web.UI.Page.User' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'

```
                    User NewUser = new User();
                    NewUser.first_name = first_name.Text;
                    NewUser.last_name = last_name.Text;
                    NewUser.email = email.Text;
                    NewUser.password = password.Text;

                    NewUser.create();
```

I created a class called User in its own code file. Maybe this code page is not accessing that class even though it was made public.

Comment: Probably you have a class named User that conflicts with the property User present in the System.Web.UI.Page class. And if you are inside your Page_Load or other methods of your derived System.Web.UI.Page page your code triggers the problem. Change the name to your User class or specify the full namespace before your User. (I.E. MyProject.Objects.User = new MyProject.Objects.User)

Comment: thanks. I tried using the namespace and it is in  a pageload function, which is a "protected void". Unfortunately, I get this error when I add the namespace: The type or namespace named 'Pet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). If I add the project name, it can't find it.

Comment: Also if your `Pet` project is compiled in the same solution you need to add to the references of the project where the page reside. (Right click on the project, select Properties page, add the reference to your own project, sorry for the possibly inaccurate menu voidce. I'm translating on the fly from my localized copy of VS)

Comment: Next time don't re-ask the same question. Possible duplicate of [C# With Asp.net MySQL with OBDC Making Login and Registration Not Working Problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485645/c-sharp-with-asp-net-mysql-with-obdc-making-login-and-registration-not-working-p)

Comment: "User" is the name of the User class. The User class is defined in a separate file. Would it help to add a "using" statement at the top of the page, and if so, how would I go about that? Thanks.

Comment: I have already suggested to rename that class to avoid confusion. Rename it to "MyAppUser" or something on this line.

Comment: Hi Steve. Thanks for the suggestions. Renaming did not resolve it. I appreciate your time. The "reference" thing you mentioned could be the issue. I reduced the question as the original text was big and convoluted--plus the code changed dramatically. Should I have just edited it there? thanks

Comment: What is the namespace used in the PageLoad and in your `User` class? They should be the same otherwise you need a using <namespace> in the Page_Load

Comment: You could post your zip in some public shared drive service like gdrive or skydrive and then share the link here.

Comment: I added a zip Project 3 to folder with the objectives text.

Comment: p.s. I'm not asking you to do my whole project, just help. If anyone else is interested, please LMK.  I know it's a holiday and many people are chilling (or still have to work today)...

Comment: Missing in registration.aspx.designer.cs `public partial class NewUser : System.Web.UI.Page`

Comment: Thanks Steve. I wonder how that happened? Thanks for taking the time to help me. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a class named User that conflicts with the property User present in the System.Web.UI.Page class. And if you are inside your Page_Load or other methods of your derived System.Web.UI.Page page your code triggers the problem.
Changing the name to your User class should resolve the problem.

Keep in mind that, if you have named your main page class `User` and now you need to change this name you should apply your new name also in the designer.cs file **keeping the correct inheritance**.

```
public partial class NewUser : System.Web.UI.Page
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Being brand spanking new to ASP.net, I had no idea about what goes on in the designer.cs files. ASP.net seems very powerful but it is SO COMPLEX.